# Missing Enable/Disable Owners on Volume

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra

I have been looking at reformatting my Time Machine backup disk as it has been quite a while and it is throwing occasional errors and needs fixing with Disk Utility.

However one thing that I found in [Apple's December 2018 post](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380) about creating the new disk is that it says "...Make sure "Ignore ownership on this volume" at the bottom of the "Sharing & Permissions"...".

OK so where is it on my current time Machine Disk?
[image: Shows image capture of area where the Ignore Ownership checkbox shoud appear]

Interestingly it does appear on other physical drives information pages, though obviously not the start up drive...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Apple post you mentioned.

Comment: @Mark Sure can <https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380> ... Hope this works haven't used the mini-Markdown format before :)

Comment: Odd my TM disk does not have that either but the disk is blue wuth the time machine logo